# Autolaunched flow in salesforce to run only when specific changes to record made?

Tags: lightning-flow-builder

I am trying to use lightning flow instead of process builder where i see an option like below which allow to run the process only when specific changes made on the record. [image]

I dont see similar option in lightning flow. Please suggest an option in case this is not available here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the decision element to do this in your flow.

[image]

I guess you can also build your own flow template if you want to reuse it within your team.